# VirtualStringTree OnNodeRightClick

Tags: delphi-7, virtualtreeview, delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I am looking for a procedure or something that gets fired if I right click on a Node (or in general on the VirtualStringTree)

I have the following scenario:

- I have my VST close to a listview.
- I can only multi select root nodes with the mouse (hold mousebutton and move the mouse)
- If I click on ANY child node (right or left) - it is selected (+ [VSelected] State)
- If I right click on a root node it selects automatically and opens a popupmenu.

Now I would like to have a different popupmenu for ( 1 common ) for all my child nodes (and only if they are selected).

Hope you can understand what I mean, thank your for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't answer your question but point you to the right event since you've said you want to have different popup menu for each node. The right click solution would have a weakness at least in missing menu key press which invokes the popup menu as well.

***1.1 How to use different popup menu for each node depending on node level ?***

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualTreeGetPopupMenu(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; const P: TPoint;
  var AskParent: Boolean; var PopupMenu: TPopupMenu);
begin
  case VirtualTree.GetNodeLevel(Node) of
    0: PopupMenu := PopupMenu1;
    1: PopupMenu := PopupMenu2;
  end;
end;
```

***1.2 How to enable right mouse button click node selection ?***

And to allow the right mouse button node selection, simply add the `toRightClickSelect` option to the `TreeOptions.SelectionOptions` option set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the normal `OnMouseDown` event, make sure the `Button` is `mbRight` and then use the `GetHitTestInfoAt` function to check which node is under the cursor (if there is any).

```
var
  HitInfo : THitInfo;
...
TreeView.GetHitTestInfoAt(X, Y, HitInfo);
if (HitInfo.Node = ?) and (HitInfo.Column = ?) then
  begin
  ...
  end;
```

There is also `OnGetPopupMenu` which gives you a node and a column and lets you return any `TPopupMenu`.

Comment: thank you. I guess missed that event because I was so focused to look for something with right click.

Comment: I know what you mean. The number of options and events on virtual tree view can be overwhelming at first :)